# Como retornar o valor de acordo com o parâmetro recebido?

Tags: java, testes-de-unidade, mock, mockito

Precisei fazer mocking com o DAO, porém o método recebe um objeto planilha e **de acordo com o  atributo id da Planilha** preciso retornar um valor diferente.

Como faço isso para comparar corretamente o ID da planilha?

Eu desejo testar o `readMetadados` que faz uso do `uploadDAO`, desejo que o retorno seja diferente de acordo com o ID da planilha que testo. Espero um erro, mas recebo um `nullPointer` justamente por causa do mock do DAO:

```
@Bean
UploadDAO getUploadDAO() {
    UploadDAO dao = Mockito.mock(UploadDAO.class);
    File myFile = new File(URL_TEST, "click/T001.json");
    Planilha planilha = new Planilha().setId("invalidFormat").setPath(URL_TEST.concat("click/T001.json"));
    when(dao.getPlanilha(eq(planilha))).thenReturn(myFile);
    return dao;
}
```

Teste

```
@Test(expected = InternalServerErrorException.class)
public void testReadMetadados_invalidPlanilha_invalidFormat() throws Exception {
    oknok.validacao.entities.Planilha actual = new Planilha().setPath(URL_TEST.concat("click/T001.json"))
                                                                .setId("invalidFormat");
    planilhaReader.readMetadados(actual);
}
```

Comment: Seu código está confuso. O que você está querendo testar?

Comment: Estou testando readMetadados, este usa o `uploadDAO` e busca pelo arquivo. Porém, de acordo com o id da planilha que envio, desejo que o mockito retorne um arquivo diferente. Não entendo como fazer isso em `when(dao.getPlanilha(eq(planilha))).thenReturn(myFile);`

Comment: @DanielaMarquesdeMorais você não teria que mockar a planilha também?

Comment: @WellingtonAvelino Planilha entidade (classe) ou o XLSX em si?

Comment: @DanielaMarquesdeMorais Panilha entidade.

Comment: Como seria mockar a planilha? É apenas uma classe de get e set, a qual eu monto nos teste somente para passar por parâmetro

Comment: Aproveitando, é uma boa prática usar uma planilha já pronta (arquivo externo) para testar? Digo do arquivo xlsx, está localizada dentro da pasta do projeto

Comment: Qual a finalidade do  @Bean ? 
a instancia do dao esta ligada de que forma com a instancia usada pela classe planilhaReader ?
O mockito retorna nullPointer por que você está pegando do método que deve consultar alguma lista de objetos Files e trocando por um único file, acho que você precisa simular essa lista 
when(dao.getPlanilha(eq(planilha))).thenReturn(Array);

Comment: Sobre a questão de usar arquivo externo, fiz um curso de teste da Caelum, bom os testes precisam ser rápidos, você pode simular a entrada de algum arquivo ou conexão com o banco, mas dedique apenas 1 teste para essa finalidade, se todo teste consulta um arquivo ou conectar no banco, você vai estar fazendo diversas vezes 1 teste redundante.

Comment: O @Bean é por causa do Autowired do Spring. Resolvi essa questão passando a url do caminho do arquivo para o mockito e para que dessa forma, retorne cada arquivo específico.

Comment: @IsvaldoFernandes O que considero confuso que a classe é justamente para leitura de planilha, utilizando Apache POI. Tive que mockar mas retornei um New File()

Comment: Não sei se entendi bem a sua dúvida, mas basta que você crie outro `when...` para outro arquivo e planilha, não? Caso não queira criar tudo na mão, sempre, use *fake objets*. [Esta biblioteca](https://github.com/six2six/fixture-factory) é legal para isto. Se possível, tente incluir a *stack trace* da *NPE* e também o mínimo do método que gera a exception, para conseguirmos reproduzir. O legal seria você incluir não coisas do seu projeto, mas algo mínimo que reproduza o problema que está tendo. Tentei reproduzir por aqui, mas acredito que não é a resposta que deseja.

Comment: @DanielaMarquesdeMorais conseguiu resolver?

Comment: @WellingtonAvelino Consegui, irei postar. Se puder dar feedbacks ou uma resolução melhor.

Comment: @WellingtonAvelino Agora estou tendo problemas com testes de integração com o Spring e Mocks hahaha

Comment: Com o Spring? qual erro?

Comment: Failed to load ApplicationContext: BeanCreationException, todos os DAO's estão mockados. Já abro outra pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foi necessário refatorar o `getPlanilha` para fazer uma busca por *id* ao invés do objeto inteiro

```
public Planilha getPlanilha(String id) {
        return mongoCollection.findOne("{validacaoId : #, tipo : #}", id, "planilha").as(Planilha.class);
    }
```

Após isso, consigo fazer que os mocks retornem o valor de acordo com o parâmetro recebido

Teste

```
@Test(expected = InternalServerErrorException.class)
public void testReadMetadados_invalidPlanilha_invalidFormat() throws Exception {
    oknok.validacao.entities.Planilha actual = new Planilha().setPath(URL_TEST.concat("click/T001.json"))
                                                                .setId("invalidFormat");
    planilhaReader.readMetadados(actual.getId());
}
```

Mocks

```
@Bean
UploadDAO getUploadDAO() {
    UploadDAO dao = Mockito.mock(UploadDAO.class);
    File myFile = new File(URL_TEST, "click/T001.json");
    Planilha planilha = new Planilha().setId("invalidFormat").setPath(URL_TEST.concat("click/T001.json"));
    when(dao.getPlanilha("invalidFormat")).thenReturn(myFile);
    return dao;
}
```